# implementing next and back buttons for a slideshow

Tags: php, database, indexing, slideshow

I'm trying to make a php slideshow and I'm almost done I just need to implement the next and back buttons which I thought were going to be easy, but apparently you can't increment indexes in php?

```
$sql = "SELECT pic_url FROM pic_info";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$count = 0;
$dir = "http://dev2.matrix.msu.edu/~matrix.training/Holmberg_Dane/";
$source = "gallery.php";

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
    $pic_array = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $pic_array[$count] = $row['pic_url'];
        $count++;
    }

    $index = 1;
    echo "<img src= ' $dir$pic_array[$index]' />";

    echo "<a href= '$dir$pic_array[$index + 1]'>next</a>";
    echo "<a href= '$dir$pic_array[$index - 1]'>back</a>";
}



$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: yeah this is not the way you want to do this, that index will change based on your sql query.  There are plenty of tutorials out there on this kind of thing, start there.

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials using Jquery and I'm doing a task that requires me to do it this way and I also have to make the same thing using Jquery. I haven't found much trying to do it this way which is why I'm asking this question.

Comment: what are all of the `columns` in `pic_info`? ie `id`, `pic_url` ?

Comment: title, comment, pic_url

Comment: what you need to understand is that PHP has nothing to do with the user's end. there is no such thing as a "php slideshow". you better read up on the differences between php and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
echo '<img src="'.$dir.$pic_array[$index].'">
<a href="'.$dir.$pic_array[($index + 1)].'">next</a>
<a href="'.$dir.$pic_array[($index - 1)].'">back</a>';
?>
```

Comment: he forgot to concat.. i fixed it for him.. but this still isn;t going to create a slideshow, it's just going to fix your markup..

Comment: How would I go about creating the slideshow? I'm lost now

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to place the url's in an array and loop over them.

```
 $urls = ['website/url/for/image/image.jpg', 'another/url/image.jpg'];

    foreach ($urls as $url) {
        echo 'a href="http://'.$url.'"> Click </a>';
    }
```

It is definitely more readable that way.

Comment: This just prints all images at once.

Comment: Just use something like Swiper or Slickjs to do this for you.

http://idangero.us/swiper/#.V1EfNEp97ms
http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/